# What intermediate steps of the Dirac Delta Function and Fourier Series am I missing in finding a solution to the Kronig-Penney Model?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, fourier-transform

## **Intro**

We're looking at the [Kronig-Penney model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice#Kronig.E2.80.93Penney_model) in class and one of the conundrums is related to the Kronig-Penney potential for a chain of $N$ atoms. I'm supposed to squeeze out some expression for the Fourier components, $U_G$, but I don't end up with the right expression, although I think I did the right stuff.

The following is given for the delta potential function,
\begin{equation}
\tag 1
U(x)=A\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-na),
\end{equation}
of which I have to show that the Fourier components are given by
\begin{equation}
\tag 2
U_G=\frac{A}{a}, \qquad G\in\mathbb{Z},
\end{equation}
using the hint that $\sum^N_{n=0}\cos(Gna)=N$.

---

## ***Now I've done the following:***

I'll start with the generalized form of $U_G$ (**I am not sure whether this expression is correct**),
\begin{equation}
\tag 1
U_G=\frac1a\int_a U(x)e^{-iGx}\mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
in which I can substitute my potential function $U(x)$ ($U(x)=A\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-na)$), to find
\begin{equation}
\tag 2
U_G=\frac1a\int_a A\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \delta(x-na)e^{-iGx}\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
$A$ is just a constant and the sum and integral signs can be swapped, so
\begin{equation}
\tag 3
U_G=\frac{A}a\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_a\delta(x-na)e^{-iGx}\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
Now by the definition of the delta function,
\begin{equation}\tag 4
\int_a\delta(x-na)e^{-iGx}\mathrm{d}x=\int_a\delta(x-na)f(x)\mathrm{d}x=f(na)=e^{-iGna}
\end{equation}
Back to our original equation,
\begin{align}
\tag 5
U_G&=\frac{A}a\sum\limits_{n=-N}^Ne^{-iGna}\\
\tag 6
&=\frac{2A}a\sum\limits_{n=0}^N\frac{e^{-iGna}+e^{iGna}}2\\
\tag 7
&=\frac{2A}{a}\sum\limits_{n=0}^N\cos(Gna)\\
\tag 8
&=\frac{2A}{a}N.
\end{align}
...which doesn't add up?

---

## **Wikipedia**

The wikipedia article on this derivation simply skips a few steps but I'm having some trouble filling those in:
\begin{align}
\tag 9
U_G&=\frac1a\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\mathrm{d}x U(x)e^{-iGx}\\
\tag {10}
&=\frac1a\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\mathrm{d}x \sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}A\cdot \delta(x-na)e^{-iGx}\\
\tag {11}
&=\frac A a
\end{align}

See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_one-dimensional_lattice#Kronig.E2.80.93Penney_model) for more info.

Comment: about the wikipedia page: your problem is with the last step of the derivation? If so note that the integral (I assumed a typo about the lower integration limit)
$$ \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} dx \,\,\delta(x-na)e^{-ikx} $$
is zero unless $na$ is in the interval $(-a/2,a/2)$. This rules out any $n\neq 0$ hence the result

Comment: @glance And it's $e^{-ikx}$ for $n=0$?

Comment: for $n=0$ you have
$$ \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} dx \,\, \delta(x) e^{-ikx} = 1,$$
from the defining properties of the delta function

Comment: @glance I can only find material claiming that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\delta(x)=1$?! The exponential factor is completely new to me here.

Comment: @glance And if I use the other rule, $\int dx\delta(x-y)f(x)=f(y)$, I end up with $\int dx\delta(x-na)e^{-iGx}=e^{-iGna}$, which gives me the wrong result (see my updated question).

Comment: The rule is that
$$ \int_a^b \delta(x-x_0) f(x) = f(x_0), \quad \text{IFF } a < x_0 < b.$$
You have to be be careful about the integration limits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20944/discussion-between-user55789-and-glance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this step,

> $$U_G=\frac1a\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\mathrm{d}x
> U(x)e^{-iGx}=\frac1a\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\mathrm{d}x
> \sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}A\cdot \delta(x-na)e^{-iGx}$$

note that the summation is an [impulse train](http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/~theussl/DA/node20.html) with spacing $a$.  Since the integral is from $-\frac{a}{2}$ to $\frac{a}{2}$, just the impulse at $x = 0$ is integrated over so only the $n=0$ term in the summation contributes to the integral:

$$U_G =  \frac1a\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\mathrm{d}x
\sum^\infty_{n=-\infty}A\cdot \delta(x-na)e^{-iGx} =  \frac1a\int_{-a/2}^{a/2}\mathrm{d}xA\cdot \delta(x)e^{-iGx} = \frac{Ae^{-iG0}}{a} = \frac{A}{a}$$