# Solution of Schrödinger equation for Dirac delta potential $V(x) = \sum_{i=1}^P \sigma_i\delta(x-x_i)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

So, I am trying to solve Schrödinger Equation for Dirac delta potential.

The Schrödinger equation: 
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\Psi(x)}{dx^2} + V(x)\Psi(x) = E\Psi(x)
$$
And, the potential looks like: 
$$
V(x) = \sum_{i=1}^P \sigma_i\delta(x-x_i)
$$

Comment: If the number of delta functions goes to infinity, this is a slightly generalized version of the [Dirac Comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb) - that might help in your search.

Comment: This is essentially a boundary matching problem

Comment: The [double delta potential](https://www.google.com/search?q=double+delta+potential) is treated in plenty of online resources and textbooks, and the tools to expand from two to $n$ deltas are identical to those used in an $n$-piece piecewise-constant potential. So: what exactly do you want to know? What is it about the procedure that is causing you trouble?

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43510/bound-states-in-a-double-delta-function-potential).

Comment: thank you for your responses.  I am taking Quantum Mechanics for the first time and in book of Stephen Gasiorowicz, I couldn't find  anything similar to this or even in wikipedia. 

My problem is that I don't know how to manipulate this V(x) potential to solve the differential equation.

Comment: Also, yes I saw double delta potentials, but  in my question it is Dirac Comb.

Comment: [Sigh](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163861/what-intermediate-steps-of-the-dirac-delta-function-and-fourier-series-am-i-miss).

Answer (score 2):

This is the Kronig-Penney model. Solve the Schrödinger equation between two Dirac peaks (easy: the particle is free) then write the continuity of the wavefunction. Integrate the Schrödinger equation around a Dirac peak (i.e. over $[x_i-\epsilon;x_i+\epsilon]$ to show that $\psi'$ is not continuous and that the discontinuity is proportional to $\sigma_i$. With the continuity of $\psi$, you now have enough equations to determine all coefficients.